# Do I use the move semantic correctly? What would be the benefit?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

I wonder if I use the `move` semantic correctly:

```
class Vertex{
    protected:
        Common::Point3D position;
        Common::Point3D normal;
        Common::Point2D uv;
        Common::Point2D tangent;
    public:
        Vertex(Common::Point3D &&position, Common::Point3D &&normal, Common::Point2D &&uv, Common::Point2D &&tangent)
            : position(std::move(position)), normal(std::move(normal)), uv(std::move(uv)), tangent(std::move(tangent)){}
};
```

**What will I achieve here with `move`?** The code for comparison (I could the `const &` too):

```
class Vertex{
    protected:
        Common::Point3D position;
        Common::Point3D normal;
        Common::Point2D uv;
        Common::Point2D tangent;
    public:
        Vertex(Common::Point3D position, Common::Point3D normal, Common::Point2D uv, Common::Point2D tangent)
            : position(position), normal(normal), uv(uv), tangent(tangent){}
};
```

**How many copies will be prevented and which of them will happen anyway?**

I would like to use the code like this:

```
Vertex * vertices = new Vertex[10000];
vertices[0] = Vertex(Common::Point3D(1,2,3), Common::Point3D(4,5,6)...);
vertices[1] = ...
```

Could I optimize it further?

Comment: Whether there's any benefit or not depends on the contents of `Point2D` and `Point3D`, and judging from their names, it's likely there's no benefit to moving.

Comment: `Point3D` is simply `class Point3D{float x, y,z;}` with some custom `set` and `get` methods.

Comment: Just copy those then or pass by reference where appropriate. There is nothing to speed up here.

Comment: @PolGraphic So no. Moving will have no benefit over copying. But the difference between those two code snippets is that the first constructor only accepts rvalues while the second accepts both lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: That's what I thought it would be. For fundamental types, moving and copying are the same, so this class wouldn't benefit from moving at all. For conventions sake, I'd probably define the constructor as `Vertex(Common::Point3D position, ...) : position(std::move(position)), ... {}` Unlike your first definition, this one will accept lvalues too (if that doesn't matter, then your first definition is fine)

Comment: Hm, so how should the `Point3D` looks to give me any benefits from move semantic?

Comment: You'll see most of the benefits with objects that are expensive to copy, either because they use additional resources or are simply very large. You'd have to do fairly unspeakable things to  three floats to have them benefit from move semantics.

Comment: Does the "fairly unspeakable things" includes performing about 1-2k such operations (calling the `Vertex` constructor) per frame in game (60 frames each second, so up to 120 thousands calls **each** second)? Marginal benefit is still a benefit for me. I just don't get when the benefit is the "absolute zero" and when it suddenly becomes "close to zero". Would I gain something with `Vertex4D{x,y,z,w}` or maybe with `Vertex10000D{... 1000 members ...}`?

Comment: @PolGraphic: No, the "unspeakable things" would have to happen every time you copy one of them for move semantics to make a difference. If it's a simple POD type like this, then moving is equivalent to copying, and there's no benefit. If copying involves something complicated (like allocating extra memory), and moving can avoid that (perhaps by taking already allocated memory from the other object), then you'll get a benefit from moving.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if I use the move semantic correctly:

By accepting only rvalue referencing you are restricting passing lvalues to this constructor. You would probably find out pretty quickly you can't use this like you would expect. If you accept the types by value...

```
Vertex(Common::Point3D position, Common::Point3D normal, Common::Point2D uv, Common::Point2D tangent)
    : position{std::move(position)}
    , normal{std::move(normal)}
    , uv{std::move(uv)}
    , tangent{std::move(tangent)}
{}
```

... you allow the user of the class to `move` or `copy` into the constructor variable, and then you always `move` into your member variable. This means you will always cause 1 copy and 1 move or 2 moves depending on how the ctor was called. Alternatively you could take by `const&` and always cause exactly 1 copy no matter what. If you want to be the undeniably fastest you would have overloads for every combination of `&&` and `const&`, but that's too much code.

> What will I achieve here with move?

Making an assumption that a `Point3D` contains just 3 ints/floats/doubles, you won't gain anything. Fundamental types don't get anything from `move`, it's the same as a copy.

The biggest benefit from moving is usually when you can 'steal' dynamically allocated memory. Think of a `vector`, it dynamically allocates an array and holds a pointer to it. When you `move` it, it can simply copy that pointer to the new object and null out the original pointer. When you copy it, it allocates new memory in the new object and copies the array (possibly element by element) into the new array. Big cost difference: an allocation and copying the elements of an array compared to just copying a pointer.

Conclusion: For your types, passing by `const&` is likely the fastest way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Would the dynamically allocated array (`Vertex * vertices`) took the benefits from `move` (in the way the `std::vector` does)?